# Immutable object as key in hash collections

Tags: java, hashmap

I have read that it is better to have immutable objects as key in a HashMap because it cache the hashcode generated.

How come an immutable objects cache the hash code with default?  Is it the real advantage of having immutable objects as keys?

Comment: And where have you read this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2393748/217862 for an example of what can go wrong with mutable keys in maps.

Comment: in here, http://javarevisited.blogspot.sg/2011/02/how-hashmap-works-in-java.html                                                        Some good developer point out here that using immutable, final object with proper equals() and hashcode() implementation would act as perfect Java HashMap  keys and improve performance of Java HashMap  by reducing collision.

Answer (score 4):

That is not really the main reason (and an immutable object might not cache its hashcode).

The real (potential) problem is that if the hashcode of a key changes while it is in a hashmap, a call to `map.containsKey(modifiedKey)` might return false, although the key still is in the map.

The only way to access it then to iterate.

Note that the actual result might vary depending on the map implementation.

See below a contrived example. The output is:

> false
>   1
>   {1=abc}

meaning that the map thinks the key is not there any more, but it actually still is.

```
public class Test2  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Mutable, String> map = new HashMap<> ();
        Mutable m = new Mutable();
        map.put(m, "abc");
        m.i = 1;
        System.out.println(map.containsKey(m));
        System.out.println(map.size());
        System.out.println(map);
    }
    public static class Mutable {
        int i = 0;
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return i;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return String.valueOf(i);
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 If the hashCode changes, it *might be found* but it's pretty unlikely. i.e. it has to change to a hashCode which would happen to be in the same bucket. Obviously TreeMap doesn't care if the hashCode changes ;)

Comment: A correction: HashMap, LinkedHashMap, Hashtable and ConcurrentHashMap caches the hashCode so it has to be exact match for the hashCode when it was added to be found. Different hash Map implementations might only require a bucket match.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes, once in the right bucket: `if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))`

Answer (score 1):

An immutable object never changes. This means that the `HashMap` does not need to recalculate hashcodes when looking up objects with this key. It calculates it once and then it can cache that value.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with caching of `hashCode()` (an immutable object could still calculate it on the fly). It has to do with the stability of the result of `hashCode()`. For mutable objects the `hashCode()` might be dependent on values that could change, if this happens you are no longer able to find the key (and its value) in the `HashMap`.