# Looking for the right collection - bidirectional unique pairs

Tags: java, collections

I need a collection in Java which represents the following data structure:
If I get the following inputs I need to store them as described below:

A->B //should be stored

A->C //should be stored

A->B  //should not be allowed (stored) anymore as it is in the collection already

B->A  //should also not be allowed (stored) as A->B is in the collection already

C->B //should be stored

D->C //should be stored

I hope you get the idea.

I tried a `HashMap<Set<String>, Set<String>>` already but mutating keysets goes wrong, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2393748/2346207

Comment: How about a `Set<Edge>` and you define the type `Edge` with the appropriate `equals` and `hashCode` methods?

Comment: @reto Looks like the right approach. Make it an answer.

Comment: @reto Could you elaborate a little more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `java.util` defaults only also, for example as set of sets:

```java
HashSet<HashSet<String>> h = new HashSet<HashSet<String>>();

h.add(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("A", "B")));
h.add(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("B", "A"))); // will be ignored
h.add(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("B", "C"))); // ok, new member
```

a bit wordy in Java for oneliners, but that works.

Comment: Actually, too wordy. For example, I think, now, when Java 7 is already the previous release, you can use it's syntax `= new HashSet<HashSet<String>>()` -> `= new HashSet<>()`. Same diamond notation can be used in `h.add` constructions: `h.add(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B"))`.

Comment: I liked @reto 's approach but yours is more clever, faster and uses the defaults, so I will mark this as a correct answer.
Can you explain why exactly 'h.add(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("B", "A")));' will be ignored?

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg you are correct, I used your suggested "abbreviations" and it still works fine! Thanks everyone!

Comment: @Anton _will be ignored_ because (A, B) set and (B, A) set are equal thus `add()` method will not insert duplicated tuple and will return `false`

Comment: Please, note, that @reto 's approach is just much more Java-style, you surely should use the special class for edge instead of using sets (by the way, unbounded by size). For example, this approach lead to absence of standard `Pair` class in Java, because `Pair` doesn't mean some concrete entity. So, @reto 's answer should be marked as solution, I think.

Answer (score 4):

A `Set<Edge>` where you define the type `Edge` with the appropriate `equals` and `hashCode` methods will work to store this information.

Your input `A->B` is represented in the class `Edge`. The class has two fields, lets call them source and destination. This wording would be in line with the arrows that you use (directed vs. undirected graph).

Tutorials like this one http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/hashcode-equals.html explain the basics of `equals` and `hashCode`. In your case it's important and an `Edge` `A->B` is considered equal to an `Edge` `B->A` (again, directions in the graph... `A<->B`)

Answer (score 1):

For example, let the `Vertex` be `Comparable<Vertex>`

As reto suggested, you should create `Edge` class with `equals` and `hashCode` overridden:

```
public class Edge {
    Vertex first, second;
    public Edge (Vertex first, Vertex second) {
        int order = first.compareTo(second);
        this.first = (order > 0) ? first : second;
        this.second = (order > 0) ? second : first;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals (Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Edge))
            return false;
        Edge other = (Edge)o;
        return other.first.equals(first) && other.second.equals(second);
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return first.hashCode() * 31 + second.hashCode();
    }
}
```

The ordering will be ignored by making `first <= second` always