# How to compose a key for a HashMap from 3 integers?

Tags: java, hashmap

I require a unique mapping from 3 integers to an object. I cannot make any assumption about the values of these integers, other than that they are positive.

I currently implement this with a hashmap like this:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 20;
int c = 30;
Map<String, MyObject> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(a + "_" + b + "_" + c, myObject);
```

While this works, it looks kinda ugly.

Is there a better alternative, without introducing clashes, and without using 3rd party libraries?

EDIT: I just realized I can actually make much more specific assumptions about my integers.  They will all be in the range 1,000,000 to 2,000,000, with their weight being at the bottom, because they are sequences that start counting at 1,000,000.

Comment: Why not make a `Key` class that generates a `hashCode` from the 3 integer values and an `equals` by comparing all 3?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Please post a somewhat more detailed version of that as the answer :-)

Comment: @AasmundEldhuset Someone will take care of it. Seems pretty straight forward.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis but how do I guarantee that there are no clashes?

Comment: And is this really an improvement over just concatenating a String?

Comment: Or just use a Map<Set<Integer>, MyObject>?

Comment: @popovitsj What do you mean clashes?

Comment: Or even Map<int[],MyObject>?

Comment: What's the range of vues that a b and c could be?

Comment: Oh, no wait, sets are mutable. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393296/how-to-use-sets-as-keys-in-java-maps

Comment: @Bohemian they are positive.

Comment: It is an improvement because you know that the key is composed of three integers, rather than an arbitrary string like "foo"; you can add accessors to get the individual integers if you want; and you can guarantee immutability of the keys, which you can't with arrays.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis sorry, if you use Key as the key then of course it doesn't matter if some hashcodes clash. But could you answer my other question, why this is an improvement over concatenating them as a String?

Comment: positive without ceiling?

Comment: @popovitsj Encapsulation and type safety. No one will try to access your map with a key as `"garbage_whatever_doesn't event matter what I put here"`.

Comment: @Bohemian, honestly, in my use case the values will not go over 10 million

Comment: @popovitsj If their max was 1 million, you could do something very neat and wouldn't need a class for the key etc. Was 10 million a considered max? Could the max actually be 1 million?

Comment: @Bohemian thinking about that, actually my range will be quite tight. They will range between 1,000,000 and 2,000,000, with the weight at the bottom of the range (they are sequences that start at 1,000,000). So I'm curious to know what you you have in mind!

Comment: @Bohemian I think I know what you have in mind... you are thinking of converting them to a long with bitshifts? `a | b << 21 | c << 42`

Comment: @popovitsj ha - yes! (I just read your comment after posting my answer). I thought I might have to explain what was going on in my impl, but you came up with virtually the same code half a day ago :)

Comment: @Bohemian I'm not sure if I'll use this in my use case though... the advantage of the solution with the Key class is that it provides clarity and validation. Maybe I'll just take this idea and just use it for the `hashCode()` on the Key class. Or I could something like `a << 10 ^ b << 5 ^ c`, since for the `hascode()` it's not a disaster to have an occasional clash.

Comment: @popo Not worth the trouble - just defer to the JDK's [`Objects.hash()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hash(java.lang.Object...)) utility method with `return Objects.hash(a, b, c);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
final class Key{
     int a , b , c;
     public Key(int a , int b , int c){
         this.a = a;
         this.b = b;
         this.c = c;
     }

     public int hashCode(){
          return (a << 10 ^ b << 5 ^ c);
     }

     public boolean equals(Object o){
          if(!(o instanceof Key))
               return false;

          Key k = (Key) o;

          return (k.a == a && k.b == b && k.c == c);
     }
}
```

this should work even for negative values.

Comment: You should make the class final, or a subclass can break intended behaviour.

Comment: thats just an example. its rather incomplete (i haven't even added all accessmodifiers). but youre right

Comment: Can you explain why you chose for `a ^ b ^ c` as a hash function? I was personally thinking about using `a * b * c`.

Comment: actually i chose it because it's aswell the way a hashcode is generated from a long-value. but xor should be faster than multiplying the values and the generated hashCodes are distributed in a more consistent way. (your hashCode is for example pretty likely to have the leastsignificant bit = 0).

Comment: Mutliplication has potential for overflow, for general values of the integers.

Comment: I get the point that this will suck if one of the integers is 0. I don't see why integer overflow is be a problem. I see that as a good thing.

Comment: @Andy Turner That wouldn't cause any troubles, you'd just loose some decimals at the beginning. Doesn't matter.

Comment: One more thing, I'm wondering if it's really necessary to do the type casting check. Why would something compare my Key class with something that's not a Key class?

Comment: That's first of all a matter of typesecurity. Here it's not that a problem, but let's assume you want to compare for example an instance of a superclass and it's baseclass. you call `baseInstance.equals(superInstance)` and a classcastexception is thrown.

Comment: Yes, but on the other hand, if my map grows extremely large, I don't want to do redundant type checking.

Comment: It's up to the programmer, what his code looks like. You **can** leave it out to improve runtime, though this absolutly not recommendable and is likely to cause exceptions.

Comment: That check is almost always going to get optimized down to almost nothing.  Keep it in for correctness; don't worry about the performance of such a cheap thing.

Comment: Better to use `Objects.hash()` than XOR for the hash for better distribution. XOR will produce the same hash (ie collisions) for any given set of 3 values no matter which fields they are assigned to (ie it is no better than `a + b + c`). Actually it's worse than `a + b + c` because the range of result values is limited to 1 - the next power of 2 after the largest value, eg any 3 values 1 - 30 when XORed will produce a result of 0 - 31, but when added will produce 3 - 90.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I'm not convinced. I realize that micro-optimization is a bad thing, but so is redundant code, and I just can't think of a scenario in which the type-check could fail.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a `Key` class like this:

```
final class Key {
    final int a;
    final int b;
    final int c;

    Key(int a, int b, int c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Key)) {
            return false;
        }
        Key that = (Key) obj;
        return (this.a == that.a)
               && (this.b == that.b)
               && (this.c == that.c);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(this.a, this.b, this.c);
    }

}
```

And make your Map a `Map<Key, MyObject>`.

One of the advantages of this over using a `String` is type safety. You won't be able to do this, for example:

```
map.put("Some arbitrary string that has nothing to do with numbers", myObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the range of each value has a maximum of 2M distinct contiguous values, which is under 2<sup>21</sup> values, and there are 3 such values, the number of distinct combinations is under 2<sup>63</sup>. This many combinations neatly (just) fits into the range of `long` values (2<sup>64</sup>), so with the right math each unique combination of a, b and c can have its own `long` value.

Here's a terse and highly performant implement ion that uses bit manipulation to get the job done:

```
// safe for a, b and c in range 0-2,097,151 (21 bits)
private static long key(long a, long b, long c) {
    return a << 42 | b << 21 | c;
}
```

If you make your map's key type `Long`, then you can use the result of this method as the key:

```
Map<Long, MyObject> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(key(a, b, c), myObject);
```

I haven't measured the performance of the `key()` method, but it would be only a few CPU cycles.

Comment: Yep - I missed that. Nice catch - your math Kung fu is obviously pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Like some answers pointed out, having your own key class will work.  Collisions are detected with hashcode and equals, as usual.

Personally, I like the option of an unlimited array of ints for flexibility.

```
public final class IntArrayKey{
    private final List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
    private final int hash;
    private final String stringValue;

    public IntArrayKey(Integer ...ints){
        values.addAll(Arrays.asList(ints));
        hash = Arrays.hashCode(ints);
        stringValue = values.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if(o == this) return true;
        if(!(o instanceof IntArrayKey)) return false;
        return values.equals(((IntArrayKey) o).values);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return stringValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Fixed.  Also removed the `static`.  That was from testing the code inside a sandbox class.