# Handling duplicate values in HashMaps

Tags: java

I have a populated hashmap in the form `Hashmap<String , ArrayList<Double>>`. There are many cases in which the values (Arraylist) are the same. What I want tro do is if the value is same , the two separate entries should be changed to one with a change in the key. For eg:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Double>> map = new HashMap<>();
ArrayList<Double> arr = new ArrayList<>();
arr.add(1);
arr.add(2)
map.put("a",arr);
map.put("b",arr);
map.put("c",arr);
```

This should result in a hashmap with a single entry :

```
{a, b , c=[1,2]}
```

I have tried to solve this for hours but am still unable to do so. A million thanks in advance.

Comment: @lucasvw I want to remove multiple values not multiple keys

Comment: java.util.HashMaps don't really work like that. A HashMap is a collection of Key,Value **pairs**, It doesn't allow multiple keys in a single entry.

Comment: But you say you want to combine keys with the same value into one key, right?

Comment: @ lucasvw as I told @ControlAltDel, I am fine with removing the old keys or any other way

Comment: How would you like to change the keys for cases where values are the same?

Comment: @krzyk I am pretty flexible on that, any way would be fine

Comment: Another question: how do you want to be able to retrive the values from the map? For example, if you combine keys as you say you want, you would no longer be able to call `map.get("c")` to retrieve the `arr` object

Comment: I wouldn't be trying to get the values from the map, I will be applying them

Comment: So you'll never need to access the values in the map? Why do you need the map in the first place?

Comment: I'm using the information to add markers to a map in android

Comment: But what do you do with the information after you add it? Why do you need a map of the information if you don't need to look it up at a later point?

Comment: @lucasvw By map I meant a google map. I am displaying the information to my client. The double values are actually latitude and longitude

Comment: The scenario you describe is basically the reverse of your data structure. Thus, swap keys and values for your map, creating a Map<ArrayList<Double>, ArrayList<String>> where your double-list is the key, and new strings get added as map.computeIfAbsent(keylist -> new ArrayList<String>()).add(newValueString)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating your custom `HashMap` by overriding `put()` should work, performance-wise it is not really efficient though.

Something like this:

```
public class CustomMap extends HashMap<String, ArrayList<Double>> {
    @Override
    public ArrayList<Double> put(String key, ArrayList<Double> value) {
        for (Entry<String, ArrayList<Double>> entry : entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue().equals(value)) {
                String oldKey = entry.getKey();
                remove(oldKey);
                String newKey = oldKey + ", " + key;
                return super.put(newKey, value);
            }
        }
        return super.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

To use it, just replace the following:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Double>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

With:

```
CustomMap map = new CustomMap();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maps relate keys with values. So even if the values are the same, you can't combine these entries because the keys are different

Comment: can't I remove the old entries and then add a new one with the updated key

Comment: You could, but it is generally a bad idea to use Collections as a key. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393296/how-to-use-sets-as-keys-in-java-maps

Comment: @lucasvw I would be grateful if you could suggest point me to how I can achieve the above, I do not mind changing the type of the value

Comment: @lucasvw not the way OP would like it to work. Using a Collection as a Key would match only if all elements in Collection are included in the lookup, rather than a lookup with just 1 of the elements