# Comparing multiple hashmaps with Set Elements in java

Tags: java

Could anyone help me to find the easiest possible solution for my scenario.

I have a Treeset with values

```
["Orders", "Creatives", "Campaigns", "Sales"]
```

and a hashmap like

```
Map<TreeSet<String>, String> tmpSet = new HashMap<TreeSet<String>, String>;
tmpSet.put(new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList("Orders", "Creatives"), "TABLE_OC");
tmpSet.put(new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList("Creatives", "Sales"), "TABLE_CS");
```

I basically want to compare the keyset of the map with the set elements and return the map values. In this case, I want to return both "TABLE_OC" and "TABLE_CS" as the elements in the set contains the keyset of the map.

Comment: That is not a good idea. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393296/how-to-use-sets-as-keys-in-java-maps)

Comment: Iterate over the keys and compare using an appropriate method like `containsAll()`. Besides that using a mutable object like a `TreeSet` as the key of a map is a receipe for disaster.